# MySQL query to get records where date+time is grater then now?

Tags: mysql

I have written this MySQL query to select all those records where date and time is greater then now, but this query do not selects a record where date is 2018-03-23, and time is 01:01:01, the current date and time is 2015-02-14 02:20:11.
please help what should I do?

```
select * from records where date > CURDATE() and time > CURTIME();
```

Comment: Can you show us the ddl and some sample date?

Comment: What are data types for `date` and `time` fields?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from records where date > CURDATE() OR (date = CURDATE() and time > CURTIME());
```

Comment: But the big question is, why are you storing date and time separately?